# Passing A Variable (Color) To a NSView?

Tags: macos, swift, nsview

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out why I'm having such a hard time passing a variable to my NSView.  Essentially, I am trying to set a variable (`myColor`) to set the color of a circle I am drawing.  The code appears like so;

```
import Cocoa

class Circle: NSView {

var myColor:NSColor? = NSColor.greenColor()

lazy var innerRing: CAShapeLayer = {
    let innerRing = CAShapeLayer()
    let circleRadius: CGFloat = 20.0
    innerRing.frame = self.bounds

    var circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleRadius, height: circleRadius)
    circleFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidX(circleFrame)
    circleFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidY(circleFrame)

    innerRing.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(circleFrame, nil)
    innerRing.lineWidth = 3.0
    innerRing.strokeStart = 0.0
    innerRing.strokeEnd = 0.75
    innerRing.fillColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
    innerRing.strokeColor = myColor.CGColor

//THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR

    return innerRing
    }()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    wantsLayer = true
    layer = CALayer()
    layer?.addSublayer(innerRing)
}
}
```

I keep receiving the error **Instance member 'myColor' cannot be used on type 'Circle'**.  If I set my `strokeColor` to be something simple, like NSColor.blueColor().CGColor, it compiles without issue.  But I've never had such issue setting a variable before, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT:  Updating with solution**

```
import Cocoa

class Circle: NSView {

lazy var innerRing: CAShapeLayer = {

    let innerRing = CAShapeLayer()
    let circleRadius: CGFloat = 20.0
    innerRing.frame = self.bounds

    var circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleRadius, height: circleRadius)
    circleFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidX(circleFrame)
    circleFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidY(circleFrame)

    innerRing.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(circleFrame, nil)
    innerRing.lineWidth = 2.0
    innerRing.strokeStart = 0.0
    innerRing.strokeEnd = 0.75
    innerRing.fillColor = NSColor.greenColor().CGColor
    innerRing.strokeColor = NSColor.blackColor().CGColor
    return innerRing
    }()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    wantsLayer = true
    layer = CALayer()
    layer?.addSublayer(innerRing)
    }

}
```

I am then calling this from another View Controller my using `cirleView.innerRing.strokeColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor`, eliminating the need for a separate `myColor` variable altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myColor` is typed as an Optional (`NSColor?`). You therefore have to unwrap it before you can get its `CGColor` property. Also, you're in an anonymous function here, so you must refer explicitly to `self` in order to access your property. Thus, this will fix the problem:

```
innerRing.strokeColor = self.myColor!.CGColor
```

Or, even better, *don't* type `myColor` as an Optional; just make it an NSColor. You can do this because you are giving it a default value right there in the declaration. You then won't have anything to unwrap and the exclamation mark won't be needed.

Comment: Hi @matt - I have indeed tried setting `innerRing.strokeColor = myColor!.CGColor` (or not making it an optional altogether; which gives me the line `var myColor: NSColor = NSColor.greenColor()`, but I still continue to receive **Instance member 'myColor' cannot be used on type 'Circle'** when I compile.

Comment: Hi @matt!  Your suggestion worked to eliminate the error in the compiler!  Thank you for that.  The problem I'm having is...this isn't actually working.  More specifically, I have a NSView in a custom table cell set to my Circle subclass.  In my NSTableViewController, I am using `cellView.circleIndicator.myColor = NSColor.redColor()`.  It compiles and runs, but the color always defaults to whatever I've set in my **Circle.swift** file.  It doesn't seem to respect the color I am setting, like it's not being passed.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @matt!  Disregard.  I still couldn't set the variable from my View Controller, but I've edited my answer with how I did get it working, thanks to your suggestion.